# SSH hangs when halting a remote system

Tags: linux, ssh, freebsd, remote-shutdown

I successfully used

```
ssh -q -i pubkey root@192.168.200.122 'halt'
```

for years now to halt a FreeBSD system (FreeNAS) from a linux box.

Suddenly, from out of nothing this stopped working: ssh hangs forever with this command. Since this is used in a backup script this is a desaster.

What could have happened that this suddenly happens? Is the problem more likely on the server side (FreeBSD) or client (Linux). How can I fix it (on the client side)?

Comment: What has changes on the server / client side when it stopped working?

Comment: Nothing that I know ;-) Otherwise I would have reverted it and tried ...

Comment: Try running `ssh` without the `-q` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your SSH client config. `TCPKeepAlive` should not be set to `no` for the client.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to ssh in manually?

```
ssh -i pubkey root@192.168.200.122
```

My only guess is for whatever reason the client's known_hosts got changed, deleted, etc.  Or the entry in it doesn't match anymore which is possible.  If openssl got changed (upgraded?) on the server side, then the known_hosts entry won't match.

And so when you ssh, even with a pubkey, you will get this if the known_hosts doesn't exist:

The authenticity of host '192.168.200.122 (192.168.200.122)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is fa:7c:54:45:70:c2:70:f9:f2:3c:c9:75:4d:83:10:5b.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

And so it is waiting for you to accept

Or you will get this if it doesn't match

test:~/.ssh # ssh 192.168.200.122
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
fa:7c:54:45:70:c2:70:f9:f2:3c:c9:75:4d:83:10:5b.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
RSA host key for 192.168.200.122 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
test:~/.ssh #

So try it manually.  If it doesn't exist, you will need to accept it and then the known_hosts entry will be created and then the next time you ssh it should be fine

If it doesn't match, then edit your ~/.ssh/known_hosts and delete the entry for that host.  Then when you ssh in again manually, accept it and recreate the known_hosts entry.

Only thing I can think of off the top of my head.  Hope that's it!

Comment: Unfortunately not. It also happens when I do it manually. I even can't kill the SSH session then with CTRL+C. I can only use CTRL+K in my screen session to kill the complete window. And login etc. is definitely successful. I can successfully issue the 'halt' command. So it seems the machine is indeed halted (I can't really verify because it's a remote box) but there is no timeout for SSH or so...

Comment: So the machine is halting but you want your ssh session to exit?  That's interesting. I would think that all along it might do this.  Are you okay with running halt in the background?  Maybe I misunderstand the issue.  So the command you run is 'halt &' ?

Comment: I just want to halt the system via SSH, yes. (and it always worked so far). Sure, running in background would be find but '&' doesn't help I think because it receives a HUP anyway.